# Firebase concurrent read/write

Tags: javascript, firebase, concurrency, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I use Firebase transactions to get compare value and then update the value of a document in a collection.

but when I use the same data and send the query at the same time, they both read the same value so the check I do pass for both, and I have a bad result a the end.
the field is decremented twice.

my transaction is:

```html
let docRef = db.collection('X').doc('SF');
let reduceValue = 20;
let transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(docRef)
    .then(doc => {
      let value = doc.data().y ;
      if (value >= reduceValue) {
        t.update(cptRef, { y:FieldValue.increment(-reduceValue) });
        return Promise.resolve('Y increased');
      } else {
        return Promise.reject('sorry y is ');
      }
    });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success', result);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give more details on how do you "send the query at the same time"? Please edit your question.

Comment: using two devices and press the button that calls this function at the same time

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question, what you are describing is the correct behaviour of a [Firestore Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) executed with one of the Firestore Client SDKs:

- You are calling twice a function that aims at decrementing a counter;
- At the end, the counter is decremented twice.

The fact that your two calls are executed "at the same time" should not change the result: The counter should be decremented twice.

This is exactly what the Transaction ensures: In the case of a concurrent edit, Cloud Firestore runs the entire transaction again, ensuring that the initial doc  (`db.collection('X').doc('SF')` in your case) has not changed during the Transaction. If it is the case, it will retry the operation with the new data.

This is because the Client SDKs use **optimistic concurrency** for Transactions and that, consequently, there is no locking of the documents.

I suggest you watch the following [official video](https://youtu.be/dOVSr0OsAoU) which explains that in detail.

---

You will also see in this video that for Transactions executed **from a back-end** (e.g. using the Admin SDK) the mechanism is not the same: **they implement pessimistic concurrency** (locking documents during transactions).